# Is this "The Daleks" comic strip fan-made?

Tags: story-identification, doctor-who, fan-fiction, dalek

Can anyone identify the following story. It has the feel of a non-canonical fan produced magazine based on the TV21 Daleks?

I'm wondering if it is was one-off, part of a fan magazine or something else.

[image: Bright Daleks comic page with the Daleks being stranded on a planet]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This image (and [another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14xxt.jpg)) were released to Brit-comic superfan [Lew Stringer's blog.](https://lewstringer.blogspot.com/)  They were apparently part of a pitched sequel to the [Dalek stories](https://lewstringer.blogspot.com/2014/09/daleks-1997.html) that ran in *Doctor Who Magazine* No's 249 - 255.

Unfortunately these two panels are apparently all that exist of these stories by the original artist, however the story will continue Issue #3 of the *VworpVworp* fanzine ([available online](http://www.vworpvworp.co.uk/latest-edition/)) with a different artist completing the work

> Thanks to John's generosity, he's sent me scans of the two unpublished
> pages of the new series that never was. **Sadly, Ron Turner passed away
> in 1998 so these were the only two pages completed,** but artist Lee
> Sullivan has stepped in to complete the six part story which will
> finally appear in Gareth Kavanagh's Doctor Who tribute magazine Vworp!
> Vworp! issue 3.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Unseen Daleks!](https://lewstringer.blogspot.com/2014/10/the-unseen-daleks.html)</sup></sub>